# get form not passing value php

Tags: php, forms, get

I have been searching and trying to find what is wrong with my code for quite a while and I wouldn't be asking this if I still had no idea what is wrong with my code.
Essentially I am echoing a get form, with a php script as it's action like this:

```html
<?php
//Add a team list and list members to each team.
$memq = "SELECT members.id, teams.team_name, teams.stage, teams.points, members.member1 FROM members INNER JOIN teams ON teams.team_name=members.team_name";
$memres = mysql_query($memq) or die ('Couldnt display members'.mysql_error());
echo "<br> Teams, Stage & Members: <br>";
while ($memrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($memres))
{
 $team_name = $memrow['team_name'];
 echo "<form method='get' action='addOne.php'><input type='hidden' name='team_name' value='$team_name'><input type ='submit' name='team_name' value='+1'></form> ";
 echo "<form method='get' action='addTwo.php?team_name=$team_name' value='<?php echo $team_name;?>'><button type ='submit'>+2</button></form> ";
 echo "<form method='get' action='addTen.php?team_name=$team_name' value='<?php echo $team_name;?>'><button type ='submit'>+10</button></form> ";
 echo $memrow['id'] . " | " . $memrow['team_name'] . " | " . $memrow['stage'] . " | " . $memrow['member1'] . " | " . $memrow['points'] . "<br>";
 
}
?>
```

I have been playing around with it and have tried quite a variety of things (having the `value =` field in the form declaration and other such), but essenially when I check the inspector in the browser it says this:

```html
<form method="get" action="addOne.php?team_name=asda">
  <input type="hidden" value="asda">
  <input type="submit" value="+1"></form>
```

So you can see that the value is actually set, but the form submission must not be working because the `if` statement in addOne.php ( `if (isset($_GET['team_name']))` ) is always returning false.

Am I missing something very simple here? Help appreciated, thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using GET variables in the action property of the form. If you set method='get' and a action with get variables there, they will be deleted and overwritten with the variables in the form. It should be following HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="addOne.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="team_name" value="asda">
    <input type="submit" value="+1">
</form>
```

and the PHP should look like this:

```html
$team_name = $memrow['team_name'];
echo "<form method='get' action='addOne.php'><input type='hidden' name='team_name' value='$team_name'><input type ='submit' value='+1'></form> ";
```

Comment: well I made it identical to this and it now throws a `addOne.php?team_name=asda:1 GET http://testphp-olivlaytchev.rhcloud.com/addOne.php?team_name=asda 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Can you give the PHP code you use, not just the snippet which generates the form

Comment: woops edited your post instead of mine, changed the OP now as well -> you can ignore the other two forms, as I am trying to get this first one running in order to proceed to the next. :D

Comment: Do you get the error when clicking on one of the buttons? Because in this case the error must be in the addOne.php file.

Comment: yes the error is only when I click, but the first line of addOne.php is `<?php
if (isset($_GET['team_name']))` so I don't see what's wrong with this

Comment: Could you please give the addOne.php code which is processing this, I cannot  just tell you what's the problem out of the first line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88199/discussion-between-oliver-and-gogolex).

Comment: Additionally there is an error in your line:
`echo "<form method='get' action='addOne.php'><input type='hidden' name='team_name' value='$team_name'><input type ='submit' name='team_name' value='+1'></form> ";` because you used 'team_name' two times as name. Just use this: `echo "<form method='get' action='addOne.php'><input type='hidden' name='team_name' value='$team_name'><input type ='submit' value='+1'></form> ";`

Answer (score 1):

you need put the attribute **name** in the input tag like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="var_1" value="asda" />
```

and then, cecibe the value like:

```
$var_1 = $_REQUEST['var_1']; //REQUEST, GET or POST
```